# Is plain wordpress admin panel safe from server-side code exectunion?

Tags: php, wordpress

Let's says I want give someone access to wordpress admin panel so he can edit posts, settings etc.

My question is: Is admin panel in plain wordpress installation safe so new user won't be able to run any PHP server-side code? He won't be able to install plugins obviously (no ftp access, chmod +r-w and on all wp folders).

he can put as many javascripts to posts as he wants, I know he will be able to hijack my cookies etc, I don't mind. I am asking only about server-side code.

Comment: can't you edit the plugin `php` in the backend to contain anything you like?

Comment: it's wordpress. you might as well assume there's essentially zero "security".

Comment: @Luke what plugin? I am using vanilla wordpress, no plugins.

Comment: @Peter Even with no plugins installed an admin account can still edit `any-of-the-theme-files.php` under the `appearance > editor` menu

Comment: If WordPress has essentially zero security then it wouldn't be the most widely used CMS in the world. In my experience it's all about how you run your server and manage the software. I've found WP to be extremely secure and reliable and much easier to manage than other popular CMS out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your WordPress installation is up to date, you are only using plugins from trusted developers, and you have your user roles properly configured for your specific security needs, then yes you can expect WordPress admin to be safe from server side scripting.

Out of the box WordPress ships with user roles that can be modified to your liking. For instance, I'm a super admin of a multisite and can access all sites and network admin, but I don't want my admins to have either. I can set the access level for network admin area, and what sites each admin can access.

This can be further customized to disable things like the theme / plugin editors so you would only be able to manipulate core files from FTP etc. Also, disable the ability to install plugins.

I use a plugin called User Role Editor and Adminimize to control various parts of any role i.e. editor, admin etc. I've also written my own plugin to further customize the user experience.

By default I believe you will find any js or other scripting gets stripped out of the wp editor in pages / posts. You can circumvent this by using a text widget or a plugin I use called HTML Javascript Adder.

[Adminimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/)

[User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)

[HTML Javascript Adder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/javascript-html-text-adder)

Answer (score -2):

To be honest this is not something that can be answered here with a cut and dry answer.

As far as I can remember there is not a location where an admin can edit a file, upload a file or enter PHP to be executed.

This does not mean that there are no ways to execute PHP however. As far as we know at present there are no known security vulnerabilities with the current version of Wordpress however only time will tell if this will remain the same. It might be possible for example to exploit a form and enter PHP that can be executed unintentionally. It may also be possible to edit the URI with PHP code that is not sanitized correctly on the server.

Take a look at this site which will show the numerous vulnerabilities that Wordpress has had in the past.

https://wpvulndb.com/wordpresses

I am sure the Wordpress developers did not knowingly release the software with these bugs but yet it happened.

Answer (score -3):

AFAIK by default you can only do that via the template editor.

Now... if you don't allow any file to be modified, in theory there is no other OOTB functionality that allows arbitrary code execution, so it *should* be safe, BUT...! It's Wordpress, come on... it has always had security issues, and it will continue to do so because it is full of legacy code and it is poorly designed.

Plus, to be honest, you shouldn't make such safety assumptions even for well engineered software.

Comment: I know it's wordpress that's exactly why I am asking my question. And you are wrong about second part, for example SO trust their software  giving me rights to write this comment.

Comment: So you know wordpress can't be assumed to be safe but your asking if you can anyway? :)
By the way, the SO comparison doesn't fit at all. They trust **their** software. You are asking if you can trust someone else's software, that has a bad reputation regarding its safety! :-P

Comment: so do you trust linux, php, apache, ngnix, python, frameworks, nodejs basically everything etc.?

Comment: of course, but for instance even a default LAMP stack needs some safety tweaking. it ultimately depends on the circumstances.
i think what you're really asking is "is it safe enough?" and nobody can really answer to that blindly.

Comment: there is no more context. vanilla wordpress and user that shouldn't have access executing any code.

Comment: Peter regardless upon whether they are trusted or not such software can become prone to exploitation. PHP itself has been the victim many bugs in the past as https://www.cvedetails.com/product/128/PHP-PHP.html?vendor_id=74 demonstrates. Exploited correctly some of these could have resulted in a server being taken over. The same can be said for Apache and Linux

Comment: then the answer is "yes, it should be safe enough, but you can't be really sure, because wordpress...". which is the TL;DR of my answer, really :)

Comment: And this would be an answer I am looking for, I downvoted only because "AFAIK" as "AFAIK" answers doesn't help at all, plus opinion on wordpress afety. it should be comment. I didn't ask for any gurantee that wordpress is safe even outside admin panel.

Comment: well, "AFAIK" is an insurance policy against the obscurity of wordpress internals :-P
zero day vulns keep popping up, so everything goes really as far as anyone knows to date.

Comment: also consider that disabling its own write access prevents auto-updating, which makes the thing even un-safer.